# Is it possible resize a ccsprite in cocos2d without using scale property?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to resize a ccsprite image.

My wanted resizing way is to decrease as pixel size without using scale property.

For example

```
    CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"iphone_cellg4.png"];
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(100, 0);
    sprite1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    sprite1.(???).width -= 50; <= Decrease 50 pixel. Is correct this way?
```

How to resize a pixel size of ccsprite without using scale property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to use a subset of the texture?
you can use

```
CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"iphone_cellg4.png" rect:CGRectMake(x,y)];
```

to make a sprite with a different size. You can also modify the displayed texture of an existing sprite with

```
[sprite1 displayedFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:CGRectMake(x,y)]]
```